# Easy to use PDF generator typescript/javascript library with table support?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to **generate PDFs** in the following layout:

[image]

**So I'd like to draw:**

- Rectangles, circles, lines, etc
- Images
- Customizable tables

Could you recommend a suitable, maintained typescript or at least javascript library?